# Multithreading callback methods

Tags: java, android, multithreading

I've got a `Service` in my application, which lets clients register to receive callbacks from the service. I've tried to implement it so that when the client callback implementations are called, they can either be run asynchronously or in order on the service thread. The specific behaviour for each callback is dependent on which method is used to register the client for callback. Clients can register with `registerClientForCallbacks` to make the callbacks occur on the main thread, or they can register with `registerClientForAsyncCallbacks` to make the callback happen on a new thread.

The problem I'm having, is that when I try to call the callbacks on new threads, the threads block on `thread.run()` until the runnable completes, effectively eliminating my attempts at multithreading. I've posted the code for my service below (with Javadoc because I know its long). Can someone please help me to understand why the threads in callAllRegisteredClients aren't being run simultaneously?

```
public class ExampleService extends Service {
    /**
     * A record of the clients which have registered to receive callbacks from this service
     * asynchronously.
     */
    private Set<ClientCallbacks> registeredClientsAsync;

    /**
     * A record of the clients which have registered to receive callbacks from this service on the
     * service's main thread.
     */
    private Set<ClientCallbacks> registeredClientsMainThread;

    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        registeredClientsAsync = new HashSet<ClientCallbacks>();
        registeredClientsMainThread = new HashSet<ClientCallbacks>();
    }

    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        return new LocalBinder();
    }

    /**
     * A binder with the singular purpose of returning a reference to the service.
     */
    public class LocalBinder extends Binder {
        public ExampleService getService() {
            return ExampleService.this;
        }
    }

    /**
     * Register this client to receive callback events from this service. Callback methods will
     * execute sequentially on the service's main thread. Consider using {@link
     * #registerClientForAsyncCallbacks(ClientCallbacks) registerClientForAsyncCallbacks} for
     * asynchronous callbacks.
     *
     * @param client the client to register, not null
     * @return true if the client is unregistered or has been
     * registered to receive callbacks asynchronously using {@link
     * #registerClientForAsyncCallbacks(ClientCallbacks) registerClientForAsyncCallbacks}, false
     * otherwise
     */
    public boolean registerClientForCallbacks(@NonNull ClientCallbacks client) {
        if (client == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("client cannot be null");
        }

        // Attempt to remove from async callbacks set (may do nothing)
        registeredClientsAsync.remove(client);

        return registeredClientsMainThread.add(client);
    }

    /**
     * Register this client to receive callback events from this service. Callback methods will be
     * executed asynchronously on separate threads.
     *
     * @param client the client to register, not null
     * @return true if the client is unregistered or has been
     * registered to receive callbacks in the service's main thread using {@link
     * #registerClientForCallbacks(ClientCallbacks) registerClientForCallbacks}, false
     * otherwise
     */
    public boolean registerClientForAsyncCallbacks(@NonNull ClientCallbacks client) {
        if (client == null) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("client cannot be null");
        }

        // Attempt to remove from async callbacks set (may do nothing)
        registeredClientsMainThread.remove(client);

        return registeredClientsAsync.add(client);
    }

    /**
     * Calls the {@link #ClientCallbacks ClientCallbacks} callback methods in all registered
     * clients. Clients registered for asynchronous callbacks will execute immediately, and
     * clients registered for sequential callbacks will be called in turn. Note that if the
     * callback methods block, then the service's main thread will block.
     */
    private void callAllRegisteredClients() {
        // First start asynchronous callbacks
        for (ClientCallbacks client : registeredClientsAsync) {
            Thread t = new Thread(new CallbackRunnable(client), client.toString());
            t.run();
        }

        // Finally start sequential callbacks
        for (ClientCallbacks client : registeredClientsMainThread) {
            client.onServiceEvent(this);
        }
    }

    /**
     * Interface allows callback events to be delivered to registered server clients.
     */
    public interface ClientCallbacks {
        public void onServiceEvent(Service service);
    }

    /**
     * A utility class which allows client callback methods to be executed asynchronously.
     */
    private class CallbackRunnable implements Runnable {
        /**
         * The client to receive the callbacks.
         */
        private final ClientCallbacks client;

        /**
         * Creates a new CallbackRunnable.
         * @param client the client to receive the callback methods, not null
         */
        private CallbackRunnable(@NonNull ClientCallbacks client) {
            if (client == null) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("client cannot be null");
            }

            this.client = client;
        }

        @Override
        public void run() {
            android.os.Process.setThreadPriority(Process.THREAD_PRIORITY_DEFAULT);
            client.onServiceEvent(ExampleService.this);
        }
    }

    /*
     * Testing
     * TODO remove
     */
    public void activateCallbacks() {
        callAllRegisteredClients();
    }
}
```

Comment: why are you calling `run()` instead of `start()` on the Thread?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must use `t.start()` instead of `t.run()`.

`t.run()` directly calls the `run()` method of your runnable. `t.start()` starts a new thread which then calls the `run()` method.

Also, you should consider using an [Executor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/Executor.html) instead of directly creating and starting threads...